system function always returning 0 and not working after it has already been called once
A command laid out like system(mkdir a && cd a && mkdir b && cd b && mkdir c) will cause C++ to not recognize any other requests made with system() only after the first request.
In my script, I have two if checks, they check if a file exists (BOTH FILES CURRENTLY EXISTS):
if (Val1 == 1){
  if(!system(mkdir a && cd a && mkdir b&& cd b && mkdir c && cd c && mkdir d && cd d && mkdir e)){
    std::cout<<"INITIALISATION 1 FAILED\n";
  }
} else {
  // else code here
}

if (Val2 == 1){
  if(!system(mkdir a && cd a && mkdir b&& cd b && mkdir c && cd c && mkdir d && cd d && mkdir e)){
    std::cout<<"INITIALISATION 2 FAILED\n";
  }
} else {
  // else code here
}

When I run the example code, I get INITIALISATION 2 FAILED and only one seems to have worked, but if I move the second one up the top then it works but says that it failed, and the other one fails but says it works.
Can somebody explain what is going on?
I just tried to run a simple system() command and ran into impossible patterns.

Don't use system calls for this (that was done in the old "C" days), in C++ you should use std::filesystem::create_directory

This is clearly not real code, as it does not compile. Please provide a [mcve] of real code. Also, you say the code "says it works", but there is no code shown that outputs such a response.

It would be system("mkdir a && cd a && mkdir b&& cd b && mkdir c && cd c && mkdir d && cd d && mkdir e")

the code i gave was just for example but the point is after i call it once it seems to just die and wont properly take any values despite the first being just as long as the second

Side note: One of the best ways to hinder debugging is to do too much in one shot. The more you do between inspection points, the more likely you won't be able to see the problem until long after it has occurred, so break things up and run them one step at a time.

Just be aware that in this case, system() launches a new command process each time it is called, so breaking out the cd commands into separate system() calls will not work as expected.

noticed i should really be using filesystem soo i switched my project to C++20 and used filesystem, i recommend doing this for anybody who stumbles upon this.

WHy do you use so many mkdir and cd commands? Why not just mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e && cd a/b/c/d/e?

@Barmar in that case, there is no need to use cd in this example (only if further commands are invoked after the mkdir in the same command line, but that is not happening in this example)

system() returns an int exit code, not a bool. The mkdir and cd commands return exit code 0 on success and non-zero on failure.  So, you are reporting failure when success is returned, and not reporting anything at all when failure is returned.
Try this instead:
if (Val1 == 1){
  if (system("mkdir a && cd a && mkdir b&& cd b && mkdir c && cd c && mkdir d && cd d && mkdir e") == 0){
    std::cout << "INITIALISATION 1 SUCCEEDED\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "INITIALISATION 1 FAILED\n";
  }
} else {
  // else code here
}

if (Val2 == 1){
  if (system("mkdir a && cd a && mkdir b&& cd b && mkdir c && cd c && mkdir d && cd d && mkdir e") == 0){
    std::cout << "INITIALISATION 2 SUCCEEDED\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "INITIALISATION 2 FAILED\n";
  }
} else {
  // else code here
}

That being said, you really should not be using system() at all for this task.  If you are using C++17 or later, you can use the <filesystem> library instead, such as std::filesystem::create_directories(), eg:
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

if (Val1 == 1){
  std::error_code ec;
  if (fs::create_directories("a\\b\\c\\d\\e", ec)) {
    std::cout << "INITIALISATION 1 SUCCEEDED\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "INITIALISATION 1 FAILED\n";
  }
} else {
  // else code here
}

if (Val2 == 1){
  std::error_code ec;
  if (fs::create_directories("a\\b\\c\\d\\e", ec)){
    std::cout << "INITIALISATION 2 SUCCEEDED\n";
  } else {
    std::cout <<"INITIALISATION 2 FAILED\n";
  }
} else {
  // else code here
}

Or use platform functions like mkdir() or CreateDirectory(), etc.

i changed it to check whether its value != 0 and it still tells INITIALISATION FAILED for both now (i made a mistake before) edit: after all of this its still not creating both directories (this is example code and the real code creates directories)

@mrneedhelp Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing comments/answers. I have reverted your edit. If you want to add more details, it should be appended to the question, not replace it. In any case, I suggest you print out the actual value that is being returned by system(), that should give you a better idea of what failure is exactly occurring. But I strongly suggest you NOT use system() at all in this situation.

conclusion if anybody stumbles upon this thread, DO NOT use system for creating directories or long commands

@mrneedhelp system() is not a good choice for creating directories only because there are better ways to handle that task which don't involve launching a command processor. There is nothing wrong with using system() when you really need it, and it works fine for long commands, you just have to pay attention that any of the commands could fail, and that system() returns an error code from the processor.
